# Установить motion в Unity через код

Tags: c#, unity3d

Каким образом установить Motion через код?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в целом зачем это нужно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не знаю каким образом, но когда в motion что-либо находится, объект "enemy" не может поменять свой scale. Придётся убирать motion и устанавливать его в нужное время

Comment: Скорее всего ты делаешь что-то не так. Motion не может влиять на scale

Comment: А ты пробуй не Skinnedmeshrenderer увеличивать скейл, а весь объект вместе с костями(или только кости), ну на крайняк просто выключить аниматор. Это решение через motion, как 2+2 считать через численные методы для интегралов

Answer (score 1):

Пока быстрое решение, где используется **[AnimatorOverrideController](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/AnimatorOverrideController.html)**, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorOverrideController.html (Unity 2017):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorChangeData : MonoBehaviour {

    private Animator animator;
    public AnimationClip clip;

    void Start () {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();            
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Z)) {
            AnimatorOverrideController myOverrideController = new AnimatorOverrideController();
            myOverrideController.runtimeAnimatorController = animator.runtimeAnimatorController;
            // Переписываем состояние Idle на другой клип
            myOverrideController["Idle"] = clip;
            animator.runtimeAnimatorController = myOverrideController;    
        }           
    }
}
```

Заметка: состояние `Idle` должно быть в Аниматоре (там где состояния Entry, Any State и Exit)